# Counting not NA's for values of some column for each value of another row

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

In R language - I have lets say I have a DF with two columns **Fam** and **Prop** both categorical, now **Fam** has repeated names like Algea, Fungi, etc and column Prop has  categorical numbers and NA's. How can I get a table/output that for each value of A it tells me how many values are not.
NA example:

```
    Fam     Prop
    -------------
    Algea   one
    Fungi   two
    Algea   NA
    Algea   three
    Fungi   one
    Fungi   NA
```

**Output**:

```
Algea 2
Fungi 2
```

I know using the count function should be a direction for the solution but can't seem to solve it, because the Fam column has repeating values.

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Fam) %>% summarise(sum(!is.na(Prop)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Four solutions:

Base R frame:

```
aggregate(DF$Prop, by=list(Fam=DF$Fam), FUN=function(a) sum(!is.na(a)))
#   Fam x
# 1   A 5
# 2   B 6
# 3   C 4
```

Base R, "table" (which is not a frame, see `as.data.frame(xtabs(...))` to see the frame variant ... a little different):

```
xtabs(~ Fam + is.na(Prop), data=DF)
#    is.na(Prop)
# Fam FALSE TRUE
#   A     5    1
#   B     6    1
#   C     4    3
```

`dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(Fam) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(!is.na(Prop)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Fam       n
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 A         5
# 2 B         6
# 3 C         4
```

`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.11.4  Latest news: http://r-datatable.com
# Attaching package: 'data.table'
# The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#     between, first, last
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[,sum(!is.na(Prop)),keyby=.(Fam)]
#    Fam V1
# 1:   A  5
# 2:   B  6
# 3:   C  4
```

---

Data:

```
DF <- data.frame(Fam=sample(c('A','B','C'), size=20, replace=TRUE), Prop=sample(c('one','two','three'), size=20, replace=TRUE))
DF$Prop[sample(20,size=5)] <- NA
DF
#    Fam  Prop
# 1    B   one
# 2    B three
# 3    C  <NA>
# 4    A  <NA>
# 5    C   one
# 6    A   two
# 7    B   one
# 8    A three
# 9    B   two
# 10   C   one
# 11   C   two
# 12   B three
# 13   C  <NA>
# 14   C  <NA>
# 15   A   one
# 16   A   one
# 17   B three
# 18   A   two
# 19   C   two
# 20   B  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Base R shortest (and fastest?) solution**

```
number.of.not.NAs <- table(df$Fam[!is.na(df$Prop)])
```

It takes `df$Fam` but chooses only elements which have not `NA` in the `df$Prop` vector positions. And then using the `table` function which you mentioned.

**Base R usual solution**

Alternatively, you can split the data frame into a list of data frame by `df$Fam`,
and then count for each data frame, how many non-NA elements are in the second column - the usual split-apply-combine way. (But I guess, the `table` method above is faster).

```
dfsList <- split(df, df$Fam)
number.of.not.NAs <- sapply(dfsList, function(df) sum(!is.na(df$Prop)))
```